# display column name into list[column]scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to insert list of column from `datframe` into a list [column] so I can perform a select request. it means want to get list of column and insert it automatically into a list [column] Any help Thanks

```
object PCA extends App{
     val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
     val strPath="C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/testBis2.txt"
     val intial_Data=spark.read.option("header",true).csv(strPath)
     //array string contains names of column
     val arrayList=intial_Data.columns
     var colsList = List[Column]()
     //wanna insert name of column into the listColum
     arrayList.foreach(p=>colsList.)

     //i want to have something like
     //val colsList = List(col("col1"),col("col2"))
     //intial_Data.select(colsList:_*).show
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use *col* function as follow:

```
var colsList = List[Column]()
arrayList.columns.foreach { c =>  colsList:+=col(c)}
```

Remember to import sql functions to use *col*:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use immutable list than the variable list by transformation like below.

```
val arrayList = initial_Data.columns
val colsList = arrayList.map(col)
```